# iPhone web App Server connection

Tags: iphone

I am developing an iPhone app which need connection to server to fetch huge data at regular interval.So need to know which way is better socket connection or using libXML

Thanks

Comment: A socket connection and libXML are not interchangeable.  libXML is a parser and doesn't manage your connection in any way.  Could you provide more information about your specific requirements?

Answer (score 2):

libXML isn't a data transfer library, and sockets don't handle XML, so if you are trying to download and process large XML documents, I'd say you need both, not one or the other.

Also, I'd be extremely wary of transferring "huge" data sets directly to an iPhone. At the very least, I'd use compression and give the user some warnings before transferring data over a 3G link.

Answer (score -1):

Whats you mean by Huge data.. whats would be the size.\n
Its better First you test with max data which is chance to come from server.